# apache module compilation failure

Tags: apache2, compiling

I was following some tutorial in web about the apache module compilation. I have already installed `apache2-threaded-dev`.

When I try to compile the example_code from apache website I get:

```
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile --tag=disable-static x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -prefer-pic -DLINUX=2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr /include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread     -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1.0   -I/usr/include/apr-1.0   -c -o mod_example.lo
mod_example.c && touch mod_example.slo
mod_example.c:13:1: error: unknown type name 'module'
mod_example.c:15:5: error: 'STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF' undeclared here (not in a function)

apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

It seems like I lack the header file.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `#include "http_config.h` at the end of your include list and the example compiles fine:

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_core.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "http_request.h"
#include "http_config.h"
```